# Grabbing what a user says without a carrier phrase. Is there an alternative to Amazon.SearchQuery?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

For the skill I'm working on, I am able to grab what a user says.  However, i need a "carrier phrase" with Amazon.SearchQuery.  At a certain point in my skill, a Carrier Phrase is not exactly user friendly.  It would be helpful for the user to just be able to say something rather than having a carrier phrase in front of it.   Like "What's {term}" .  I'd like to be able to put just "{term}" in that intent, but it's not possible.

I read that Amazon.LITERAL used to be a solution to this, but it's deprecated now and is only supported for current skills in production.

Comment: `SearchQuery` and `LITERAL` are/were used to catch multiple words and phrases but if you only want a single slot to be spoken and caught, that is possible during slot elicitation. Only the utterances to trigger an intent would need a "carrier phrase" to recognize which intent.  But once you are in an intent, you can elicit specific slots with a question, and the user can reply with a single word to fill that slot. Using `dialog.Delegate` or `dialog.ElicitSlot` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a space as the carrier phrase with `AMAZON.SearchQuery`: " {term}".

Comment: why is amazon like this T.T

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has fixed the "issue" where you can use a space as the carrier phrase. It is no longer possible. You now have to do dialogue delegation.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this behavior in a certain part of your skill, [slot elicitation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#elicitslot) is likely your best bet. This will allow this slot to not negatively impact the rest of the language model. You can use this with various slot types including, I believe, AMAZON.SearchQuery.

By keeping this only in a certain flow of your skill, you can take full advantage of Alexa's language parsing, to avoid having to do so in your own skill (let Alexa tell you the Intents and Slots versus trying to REGEX match). And still be able to elicit the user's full response when needed.

Here's the official blog post on ElicitSlot (v2 Alexa Node SDK): https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/dbceb5dd-3c4d-40f1-be22-172f4050fbcb/building-conversational-alexa-skills-how-to-dynamically-elicit-slots-based-on-a-previous-answer-using-dialog-management

And an older one (v1 Alexa Node SDK):
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/5fe7565a-9547-4e03-be36-6c62ed356d57/dynamically-elicit-slots-during-dialog-management-based-on-previously-given-slot-values

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use AMAZON.SearchQuery without a carrier phrase if you're inside a dialog (i.e. the utterance that includes the slot is not an intent sample utterance but a slot sample utterance). So if you can trigger a dialog you can elicit the slot when the value is missing and accept a response without an anchor.